# ASP.NET Core: UsePathBase extracts pathbase from path but MapControllers() does not consider path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

I used UsePathBase in a dotnet 2.1 application.

```
app.UsePathBase("/app1"); // extract /app1 from path 
app.UseMvc(routers => ...) // routes consider path only
```

This does no longer work in dotnet 6: When i use

```
app.UsePathBase("/app1");
app.MapControllers(); // controller routing does not consider the reduced path
```

While before

```
"/app1/home/index" routed to HomeController, Index method
```

this now fails to route anywhere.

Am I doing something wrong?

I diagnosed with

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("=> {0}", context);
    return next.Invoke();
});
```

which shows that UsePathBase works, its the later routing in MapControllers that does not work. At least that is what I get out of that observation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add explicit call to `UseRouting` after `UsePathBase`:

```cs
app.UsePathBase("/app1");
app.UseRouting();
app.MapControllers();
```

[Read more](https://andrewlock.net/using-pathbase-with-dotnet-6-webapplicationbuilder/).

P.S.

Was not able to repro in .NET 7 solution, only in .NET 6 one, maybe it was fixed/reverted.

Comment: Meanwhile installed dotnet 7 and check it there. As you say, this was fixed. The call UseRouting in fact fixes it on my side too. Excellent. Either I move up to 7 or keep it with that. Thank you very much.

Comment: This does indeed seem to have been fixed in ASP.NET Core 7: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38448

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 6, the `UsePathBase` middleware has been replaced with the `UseRouting` middleware.

The `UseRouting` middleware is responsible for both routing and path base handling.

to set a pathbase in .NET 6, you may try something like this:

```
app.UseRouting(routes =>
{
    routes.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
        constraints: new { id = new IntRouteConstraint() },
        dataTokens: new { pathBase = "/app1" }
    );
});
```